# Problem with ToolTip in Windows Form(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, tooltip

I have form with 4 buttons and Image. For all these controls i have added tool tip by using the following code

```
 ToolTip objToolTip=null;
    .....
    public Form1()
    {
        objToolTip=new ToolTip();
    }
    .....
    //Used to set the button lables based on Data from database
    private void SetButtonlabels()
    {
        objToolTip.SetToolTip(btnSAPConnect, "Connects to SAP");
    }
```

the problem is, Once the form is opened, the tool tips are not coming immediately even if we move our mouse over the control. But Once i click on the form, then tool tips are working properly. I am not sure which is causing the problem.

Can anybody please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Where do you call the SetButtonLabels() method ?

Comment: I am calling this method on Form Load.

Comment: You need to simplify your code, and just try to put following code immediately after InitializeComponent():
objToolTip=new ToolTip();
objToolTip.SetToolTip(btnSAPConnect, "Connects to SAP"); If you still get the same result, I think you need to provide more real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just set focus on one control on the form. It started working.

Answer (score 2):

You said this:

> Once the form is opened, the tool tips are not coming immediately even if we move our mouse over the control. But Once i click on the form, then tool tips are working properly.

This leads me to think it's standard windows behaviour, and that your form just isn't getting focus when you open it.  Tooltips in many apps will only work if their parent window is activated.

Comment: i have tried with activating the window. I have used the following code  "objForm.Activate()". But still it's behaving the same.

Comment: +1 I agree that's the reason. The form got focused after OP's click so the tooltip is working since then.

Comment: @Dinesh: Posting the full code to your form might help, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps. It solved the problem i had of the tooltip not showing on the form_load event.
I noticed the tooltip working after i manually clicked on my WindowsForm control.

For some reason it won't work until your WindowsForm control is active (Usually once a user clicks on the Form).

So to solve this you will need to activate your Form behind code.

```
this.Activate();

ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.ToolTipTitle = "Info";
toolTip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
toolTip.UseFading = true;
toolTip.UseAnimation = true;
toolTip.IsBalloon = true;
toolTip.ShowAlways = true;
toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
toolTip.InitialDelay = 1000;
toolTip.ReshowDelay = 500;
toolTip.Show("This is button1", button1, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

call SetButtonlabels() from constructor of form1

Answer (score 0):

In wich method you call SetButtonlabels()?

Try to call it after the initialization of the form.

Comment: I am calling this method on Form Load.